# Android Virtual Manager not using GPU

Tags: android, gpu, cpu, virtual-device-manager

specs:

```
I5 3500k
HD 7870 AMD
```

Well I try using an emulator in Eclipse but it's pretty sluggish even with my i5 3500k. I found out that it only uses one core. So what I did is check the box that said "use Host GPU" to hopefully uses the horse power of my GPU. But when I check MSI burner, my GPU usage is 0%. And one of my CPU cores still uses over 95%. It also has the same performance. How come it's not utilizing my GPU after checking the used Host GPU.

Comment: PS::::I'm using Eclipse IDE

Comment: There is no such thing as an "i5 3500k" - did you mean 2500k?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With i5 3500K you can only use ARM based emulator instead of Intel's x86 emulator, which is 10~20 times faster (I think i5 misses these CPU extensions:  EM64T, Execute Disable (XD) Bit), see here for [x86 emulator support requirement](http://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/installation-instructions-for-intel-hardware-accelerated-execution-manager-microsoft).

For solve your speed issue, I would strongly recommend using [Genymotion](http://www.genymotion.com/), it provides fast x86 emulators with Eclipse integration, and I have not encounter any issue with it for the time I've been using it.

Comment: ok thanks, I just hope AVD would be able to utilize my GPU after checking "Host GPU usage"